# FFMPEG concat command, Error initializing complex filters

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to concat/merge two video files, the first video file has no sound, and the second has sound. I have tried multiple commands but in most of them the video playback speed was changed and output was not as expected, currently, I'm trying the following command but it shows the error "Error initializing complex filters."

Command:

```
"-i " + clipUri + " -t 0.1 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -i " + videoUri+ " -filter_complex " +
            " [0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]" +
            " [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]" +
            " [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]" +
            " [v0][2:a][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" +
            " -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart " + outputUri
```

I am not really sure what is the issue is, can anyone check this command and let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Missing semicolons between filterchains.

Comment: Also, lavfi input will likely cause an issue. Try `aevalsrc=0:n=1:c=stereo:s=48000` to specify silence and produce only 1 sample (and let `concat` to extend it). Without `n=1` ffmpeg will run forever as `concat` uses the duration of the longer of video and audio.

Comment: Thanks @kesh , should i replace `anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000` with `aevalsrc=0:n=1:c=stereo:s=48000` ?

Comment: yes. I'm not sure if `anullsrc` guarantees its samples to be 0.